# Querying Parse.com and trying to display in Android ListView

Tags: android, parse-platform

Using Parse.com for the first time . Here's the problem,I am trying to query the Parse.com and then displaying it in android listview Log is getting printed properly but some issue in displaying it in listview

Here's the code

```
 ArrayList<String> mFuncDate = new ArrayList<String>();
 private ListView lv;
 lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myList);
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("GameScore");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(List<ParseObject> scoreList, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                //Log.d("score", "Retrieved " + scoreList.size() + " in list " + scoreList.get(0).getString("ClientName"));
                for(int i=0;i<scoreList.size();i++)  {
                     Log.d("data","Retrieved Object is " + scoreList.get(i).getString("Date"));  
                     mFuncDate.add( scoreList.get(i).getString("Date"));

                }  
            } else {
                Log.d("score", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });

    //String arr[]=mFuncDate.toArray(new String[mFuncDate.size()]);
    lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 ,android.R.id.text1 ,mFuncDate));
```

Where am I going wrong ?

Updated:
The problem is I can not see data getting updated in my listview, After trying so much time When I run this app when my screen is off I can see the listview getting updated but then normally I can not see anything in the listview ... I think it is something related to findInBackground so need help

Comment: Can you describe the issue you're facing?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()  if you think the date values are getting to the field 'mFuncDate' and just not showing , then u can try a notify.

Comment: @RobertRowntree : yes dude Now its working properly I tried notifying the listview ...Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I tried to update the listview by calling listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() after querying is done, in order for the list to repaint using the new data.